# QGIS-GRASS firespread simulation module

Tags: grass-gis, qgis-2

I'm trying to do some fire spread simulations in QGIS with GRASS fire spreading simulation module. QGIS ('Processing Toolbox' > 'Geoalgorithms' > 'Misc' > 'Fire spreading simulation') GUI.
Already searched in help files (insufficient information), asked, googled...

Is there anyone that knows how to work with this module?
Can you explain (or point to a tutorial on) how to run the module and what are the input formats?
(ASCII, GeoTiFF, can it be .shp for ignition?, fuel model defs: is it FARSITE/FlamMap fuel models or personal fuel models?)

Comment: Your question is a bit broad as it stands. What specifically are you having trouble with? What is or isn't working? Please **edit** your question to describe in detail what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: Describing your input data and what you have tried will help us to answer!

Comment: What's wrong with the [manual](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass71/manuals/r.spread.html)? It has the function calls, data types, explanations, examples and even a full step-by-step script incl. sample data.

Comment: The data need to be in a GRASS GIS location to be used, hence you need to import them into GRASS GIS.